# Python move cursor to end of .txt lines

Tags: python

I need to write() text at the end of every line in  a text file. How do I point the cursor to the end of a specific line.

Note: seek(0,2) will put me at the end of the file, but I need the end of each line.

Appreciate the help guys - I've combined your solutions to achieve what I need:

```
AllLines = [ (str.rstrip('\n') + 'Val2' + "\n" ) for str in AllLines ]
```

I can then write AllLines to a new output file.

Comment: are you writing the same text at the end of every line?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite characters or insert new ones?  You can't do the latter, I'm afraid, at least not in-place where everything will just be shifted.

Comment: Thx Joran. I am trying to write() different text at the end of every line. That text depends on another value within the line.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this in two steps. Since it's safer to create a new file, you could:

```
with open("input.txt") as infile, open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.rstrip("\n") + "added text\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_lines = []
with open("my_file") as f:
       new_lines = [line.strip("\n")+"some_ending_stuff" for line in f]
with open("my_file","w") as f:
       f.write("\n".join(new_lines))
```

something like that should work

Comment: You can change the "some_ending_stuff" to a function like make_ending_stuff(line), I believe, which would satisfy the OP's need to dynamically append line-specific ending stuff.